# ‘It would be better dealt with’ VS. ‘It would better be dealt with’

Tags: word-choice, would

> This problem **would be better dealt with** through a view on the
> economy.
>
> This problem **would better be dealt with** through a view on the
> economy.

Which one is the correct/better choice?

Answer (score 4):

The first one is idiomatic, the second isn't.

*This problem would be better dealt with by...* means *A better way of dealing with this problem would be to...*

You may be confusing the second with *had better*, a strong recommendation to do something. *You are wet through - you had better go indoors and change into dry clothes.*

Comment: I want to say a very good suggestion is to deal with the problem …

Comment: Then it's _had better be dealt with_, if you are just saying 'Deal with it!' and not recommending an alternative approach.

Comment: Not just ‘deal with it’, but ‘deal with with a view on the economy’’.

Comment: [Just a link to Google ngrams to support your first statement:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+better+be+dealt+with%2Cwould+be+better+dealt+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20better%20be%20dealt%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%20be%20better%20dealt%20with%3B%2Cc0) Good thinking on the possible source of confusion.